# A Checkmate of Dubious Legality

Tags: chess, retrograde-analysis

[image]

[Full-size image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gdlB.jpg)

Black has just delivered checkmate in the above position - but **is the position legal?**

If no, explain why.

If yes, give Black's mating move.

FEN: 3r4/2r4b/8/8/8/3Kp3/5k2/8 w - - 0 1

URL: [lichess.org](https://lichess.org/editor/3r4/2r4b/8/8/8/3Kp3/5k2/8_w_-_-)

---

<sub>Also hello, fellow puzzlers! Long time, no see!</sub>

Comment: Welcome back, and very nice puzzle!

Comment: Just out of curiosity - to the two downvoters, why the downvotes?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I claim that

> **yes**, the position is legal.

The reason:

> The last move cannot have been by Black's rooks or bishop, because those would leave a piece attacking White. So those pieces must have been fixed, and there must have been pieces blocking those lines of attack.
>  
>   But how is it possible for both of those pieces to disappear in a single move? Only one could have been taken in a capture, so the other piece is Black's. But then which piece could capture from a square and then *not land on* that square? There's only one way that could happen: **an en passant capture**, d4xe3.
>
>  [image]

Comment: I suppose this was a tad simpler than I thought, lol - looks like you'll get the check, Deus. Nice answer as well, @El-Guest

Comment: @Brandon_J Nah, I don't think it was as easy as our three answers would imply! You just happened to post it when two chess fans were online (and also I was here too).

Comment: Seems a bit of a trend, but why is it every time I see an "impossible" chess puzzle, 
rot13(gurer'f nyjnlf na ra cnffnag vaibyirq)?

Comment: This is probably the most famous retrograde analysis puzzle in existence, so it's no surprise that it was answered so quickly by three people...

Answer (score 8):

I think that:

> Yes it is legal.

The last sequence is

> Bh7+ e4 
>  dxe4 e.p. # !!

Answer (score 5):

It's easily legal. Black's last move was:

> dex3# en passant!

Here's a possible sequence of the last few moves:

> 1. Rh7 Bxh7+ 2. e4 dxe3# *